# SOAP-UI javax.net.ssl.SSLException

Tags: ssl, soap, ssl-certificate, soapui, embedded-jetty

Below error snippet is thrown when I am trying to Create New Soap Project in SOAP-UI. The service is running on my local machine.

> Wed Dec 20 10:05:28 IST 2017:DEBUG:I/O error closing connection
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection
>   during handshake at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(Unknown at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:131)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not resolve this, I have to disable ssl and test my cases.